# Triggers en postgres

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, trigger, plpgsql

tengo una tarea de disparadores en postgres, tengo una tabla "zapateria.empleado", lo que quiero es insertar resgistros, pero que automaticamente me agregue en un campo la fecha actual y que calcule si es mayor de edad la persona que ingrese, pero eso no se como se hace, ejemplo:

```
create table zapateria.empleado(
id_e int not null,
nombre varchar(100),
fecha_actual date,
fecha_de_cumpleaños date,
puesto varchar(100)
);
```

pero lo que quiero, es que al agregar algunos campos, que automaticamente se agregue el de fecha_actual y que me diga si es mayor de edad solamente, pero con los triggers :(

```
create or replace function prueba() returns trigger as $$
declare
begin
 ---- aqui no se que ponerle sobre eso
return
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger disparador before insert on zapateria.empleado for each statement execute procedure prueba();
```

tengo eso, pero como le haria con esa duda? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primera instancia creo que vas a necesitar una nuevo campo para indicar si el empleado es mayor de edad o no. Entonces:

```
create table zapateria.empleado(
id_e int not null,
nombre varchar(100),
fecha_actual timestamp,
fecha_de_cumpleanos timestamp,
puesto varchar(100),
esmayor char(1)                --nuevo campo (S/N)
);
```

Ahora creamos la función:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fprueba() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
DECLARE
   edad int=0;       
BEGIN
    new.fecha_actual = (select NOW());
    edad = (SELECT datediff('year', new.fecha_de_cumpleanos, new.fecha_actual) ); 
    IF edad >= 18 THEN 
       new.esmayor='S';
    ELSE
       new.esmayor='N';
    END IF;

    return new;-- el return es muy importante
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

y finalmente el trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tprueba before insert
on zapateria.empleado for each row
EXECUTE PROCEDURE fprueba();
```

Comment: muchas gracias :)